# Lining up columns without tables or colspan

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I'm trying to find a solution to laying out forms in our app (ported from Silverlight). We like labels to up, are trying to do this without tables, but there's a fundamental problem that tables solve I'm not sure how to address any other way.

Here is an example ([plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RrNDEbaqtcYSabxCsPh7?p=preview)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      h1 {
          font-size: 1.1rem;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      }

      td {
        vertical-align: top;
        padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
      }
      </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td colspan='2'><h1>This is a header that should span columns.</h1></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>
                label:
                  <div>(This label is extra</div>
                  <div>tall because of these</div>
                  <div> extra lines.)</div>
              </td>
              <td><input placeholder='search for stuff'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>this is the longest label:</td>
              <td><input placeholder='search for stuff'>
                  <div>This content is extra tall.</div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>longer label:</td>
              <td><input placeholder='search for stuff'></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td colspan='2' class='my-header-style'><h1>This is a header that should span columns.</h1></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>long label:</td>
              <td><input placeholder='search for stuff'></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>another label:</td>
              <td>
                  <div>This content is extra tall.</div>
                  <div>This content is extra tall.</div>
                  <div>This content is extra tall.</div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>short label:</td>
              <td><input placeholder='search for stuff'></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

We have two groups of "label: input" lists, each with their own headings. **The leftmost-column adjusts to the width of the widest label in either group, and simultaneously each row also adjust to the height of the tallest element.**

**How do I achieve this same behavior without tables?** When people are talking about "tableless" layout, is that only for things that don't care about content size for their layout?

Comment: use `div` for creating the layout

Comment: @geo Then how do I get the first column to adjust to the width of the widest label across all the columns?

Comment: Code has to go in the question, not on an external code-hosting service.

Comment: Then why was the topic put on hold as off-topic? What does that have to do with including code inline? I've fixed that. Do I need to repost the question or will you guys unlock it? Given how often people are told to not use tables, I would imagine regulars here should have a ready answer for a trivial table layout problem, but instead you lock the post inappropriately and delete comments. It's bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Uh, sorry. You actually can do more than two elements per line, but (as usual with float: right) you have to put them in reverse order.

---

If you must not use a table: Add a div for each row and put a invisible horizontal rule between them to keep them from piling onto each other.  Also: a float: left to the labels and a float: right to the input boxes.  <strike>It works, but I would not know how to make a line with three or more elements, like: Born on: Month/Day/Year, work.</strike>

Anyway, here is how you can do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE=html>
<html>
   <style>
       * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
       }
       body {
          float: left;
       }
       hr {
          clear: both;
          border: none;
       }
       p{
          float: left;
       }
       form {
          float: right;
       }
   </style>
   <body>
       <div id = "row_1">
              <p>looooooooooooo <br /> ooooooooooooo <br /> ooong label: </p>
              <form><input type="text" placeholder="Second" /></form>
       </div>
       <hr />
       <div id = "row_2">
              <p>short</p>
              <form><input type="text" placeholder="First" /></form>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```